# Bot IRC to show feeds does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, feed, irc

I am developing a bot for IRC in NodeJS, the bot enters the channel but it does not show the latest feeds, also show any error in console.
I'm testing initially with the feed from CNN:

```
http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_latest.rss
```

notify.js

```
var FEEDSUB = require('feedsub');
var IRC = require('irc');


// Set up your little spambot
var server    = 'irc.servercentral.net';
var bot       = 'feed-bot';
var channels  = ['#testme'];
var feed      = 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_latest.rss';
var interval  = 1 // how often to poll the feed, in minutes?


client = new IRC.Client(server, bot,
                        {
                          channels: channels,
                          realName: 'nodejs IRC bot',
                          autoRejoin: true,
                          autoConnect: true,
                        });

reader = new FEEDSUB(feed, {
  interval: interval,
  autoStart: true,

});

reader.on('item', function(item) {
  client.say(channels, item.title + ': ' + item.link);
  console.dir(item.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your bot is trying to "client.say" things before even being connected to the IRC-server/channel.